# How to prevent some new buffers from splitting the window?

Tags: window-splitting

Is it possible to have new buffers created by a spesific command (`vc-diff` for example) use the same viewable area as the current buffer?

Currently it creates a split window, which I need to manually close after using the buffer and deleting it.

Comment: Same problem here as in your other thread -- i.e., the offending code is `(pop-to-buffer (current-buffer))` within `vc-diff-internal` -- see comments in related thread for possible solutions:  http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/29665/how-to-delete-a-diff-buffer-after-running-jump-to-source

Comment: You may wish to consider asking a specific question:  "**How do I force `(pop-to-buffer BUFFER)` to *temporarily* behave like `(set-window-buffer (selected-window) BUFFER)`?**"  FYI:  As far as I can tell, your question has nothing to do with `frame`.

Comment: Ah, I thought this was the correct terminology, updated the question. At the time of asking I wasn't aware of `pop-to-buffer`. I think its good to word questions from a user perspective when their not specifically about internal API's.

Answer (score 3):

There is a global option to prevent splits from being opened:

```
(setq pop-up-windows nil)
```

When writing scripts you can locally assign this which won't apply outside the scope of the function, eg:

```
(defun vc-root-diff-fullscreen ()
  "Open a diff of the repository in the current frame."
  (interactive)
  (let ((pop-up-windows nil))
    (vc-root-diff nil)))
```