# Prevent screen splitting by julia-repl

Tags: window-splitting

I want to prevent `julia-repl` from splitting my screen, which seems like a common request given the numbers of questions I have found relating to this. Drawing on advice found [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/29671/30563) and [here](https://github.com/nex3/perspective-el/#some-musings-on-emacs-window-layouts), I came up with the following code for my `init.el`:

```
(setq display-buffer-alist
             '((".*" (display-buffer-reuse-window display-buffer-same-window))))

(setq display-buffer-reuse-frames t)

(setq pop-up-windows nil)
```

And yet when I open Emacs (`emacs`) and start `julia-repl` (`M+x julia-repl`), it **still** splits the window. My understanding is that the regex in the first command should catch *all* buffers and prevent splitting.

I also tried,

```
(add-to-list 'display-buffer-alist
           '(".*". (display-buffer-reuse-window .
                                  ((reusable-frames . t)))))
```

from [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/338/30563), too, without any success. What am I doing wrong here? Is this a quirk of `julia-repl` since the standard solutions don't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're referring to this piece of code: https://github.com/tpapp/julia-repl/blob/d073acb6339e99edf77833f82277afd9a076f16a/julia-repl.el#L449-L454

It doesn't use `display-buffer` internally, so customizations to `display-buffer-alist` have no effect.  Ask the developer to replace `switch-to-buffer-other-window` with `pop-to-buffer` or better, hand in a pull request.  In the meantime redefine the command in your init file as follows:

```
(with-eval-after-load 'julia-repl
  (defun julia-repl ()
    "..."
    (interactive)
    (pop-to-buffer (julia-repl-inferior-buffer))))
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! Is a benefit of `switch-to-buffer-other-window` over `pop-to-buffer`? (I'm just wondering why it would've been chosen instead.)

Comment: For some reason few people are aware of `display-buffer`, so my guess is lack of education.